# Enable overlay scrollbars in themes that have them disabled

Tags: themes, overlay-scrollbars

When I use Numix (`apt install numix-gtk-theme; gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "'Numix'"`), I get old-style scrollbars. I expect there is some way to force-enable overlay scrollbars even in some of the applications that don't support them by default.

If there's no such general solution, let's at least focus on Numix.